# How to load render giving a condition 'if' in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm using a debug mode in Chrome browser and the simulator expo in my phone for iOS. In my App, I want to render but this render, depends of 'X' value.

So I have window 1 and window 2 and I want that:

- if X is === null, then load window 1 and window 1 is going to window 2
- if X is!== null, then it loads directly into window 2 without passing window1.

**This is my All Imports**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, TextInput, Alert,ScrollView,AsyncStorage} from 
'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
```

**My Css For my Component**

```
const myStyle = {
principal: {
    paddingTop: 17,
    paddingLeft: 2,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
caixa: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: 300,
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 300,
    borderColor: 'black',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 20,
},
inputPin: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: 290,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 15,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginTop: 60,
    marginBottom: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    //paddingLeft:20,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center'
},
bemVindo: {
    fontSize: 40,
    marginBottom: 20,
},
botao: {
    alignItems: 'center',
},
texto: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
   }
  }
```

**I declareted my class with extends**

```
let mgm = '!!Ups, Inseriu O Pin Errado, Insira O Correcto';

export default class PaginaInicial extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isLoaded: true}
    }
    HttpRequest(){
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://api.feetit.com/shoestorebranch/auth?
 key=q59Sgv0sRr0i9Qh00aWM071hB76NZh9WcW4o3HPPpw847OT8T17Sq62n3O7FTT9n',
        data: {
            loginHash: this.state.codigoPin,
        }
    }
    ).then((response) => {
        //AsyncStorage.removeItem('localData', () => {});
        this.setState({dados: response.data.response})
        console.log('SUCCESS');

        if(this.state.dados.admin === null){
            Alert.alert('Loja sem Administrador atribuido, por favor 
          contacte o suporte.');
        }else{

            //console.log(this.state.dados);
            let tmp_localData = {};
            console.log("tmp_localData: ", tmp_localData);
            AsyncStorage.getItem('localData', (err, result) => {
                tmp_localData = result;

            }).then( (result) => {
                    if(tmp_localData == null) {
                        tmp_localData = {
                            "ShoeStoreBranch": null,
                            "User": null
                        }
                    }
                    if (!tmp_localData.hasOwnProperty("ShoeStoreBranch")) {
                        tmp_localData.ShoeStoreBranch = {};
                    }
                    tmp_localData.ShoeStoreBranch = {
                        "shoeStoreBranchID": 
           this.state.dados.shoeStoreBranchID,
                        "name": this.state.dados.name,
                        "ShoeStore": {
                            "shoeStoreID": 
           this.state.dados.shoeStore.shoeStoreID,
                            "name": this.state.dados.shoeStore.name
                        }
                    };
                    tmp_localData.User = {
                        "userID": this.state.dados.admin.userID,
                        "displayName": this.state.dados.admin.displayName,
                        "email": this.state.dados.admin.email,
                        "avatar": this.state.dados.admin.avatar,
                        "gender": this.state.dados.admin.gender,
                        "Session": {
                            "token": this.state.dados.admin.token
                        },
                        "FootID": this.state.dados.admin.FootID
                    }
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('localData', 
           JSON.stringify(tmp_localData), () => {});
                    this.props.navigator.push({id: 'MenuPrincipal'})
            });
            //var tmp_dados = this.getState()
            //var qqer =this.state.dados.admin.token;
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(qqer));
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
            if (error.response) {
                // The request was made and the server responded with a 
                 status code
                // that falls out of the range of 2xx
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
                if(error.response.status === 403){
                    console.log('App não tem autorização',error.message);
                    Alert.alert('App não tem autorização');
                }else if(error.response.status === 404){
                    console.log('PIN inválido',error.message);
                    Alert.alert('PIN inválido');
                    AsyncStorage.getItem('localData', (err, result) => {
                        console.log(result);
                    });
                }else if(error.response.status >=400 && 
       error.response.status <500){
                    console.log('Erro, por favor contactar o 
       suporte',error.message);
                    Alert.alert('Erro, por favor contactar o suporte');
                }else{
                    console.log('Erro interno, por favor contactar o suporte',error.message);
                    Alert.alert('Erro interno, por favor contactar o suporte');
                }
            } else if (error.request) {
                // The request was made but no response was received
                // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
                // http.ClientRequest in node.js
                console.log('erro de ligaçao',error.message);
                Alert.alert('erro de ligaçao');
                console.log(error.request);
            } else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                console.log('erro de codigo no then',error.message);
                Alert.alert('App error');
            }
            console.log(error.config);
            //console.log('Erro ao imprimir ao enviar os dados')
        });
}

componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('localData').then((result) => {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false
        });
    });
}
```

**The funtion that i am using is something like this:**

```
render(){
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
        if(result.hasOwnProperty("User") && result.User.hasOwnProperty("Session") && result.User.Session.hasOwnProperty("token") && (result.User.Session.token).length > 0) {
            console.log('USER JA LOGADO? -> SIM');
            return
```

**My scene than i want to change if state.isloading is false**

```
            {this.props.navigator.push({id: 'MenuPrincipal'})};

        }
    }
```

**here is the when state.isLoading is true**

```
        const {principal, caixa, inputPin, bemVindo, botao, texto} = myStyle;
        return (
            <View style={principal}>
                <View style={caixa}>
                    <Text style={bemVindo}>Bem Vindo</Text>
                    <Text style={texto}>Para que possamos identificar-lhe, Indique a baixo o código pin</Text>
                    <TextInput placeholder='Código da Loja' style={inputPin}
                               onChangeText={(textoInput) => this.setState({codigoPin: textoInput})}
                    />
                    <Button title='Continuar'style={botao} onPress={() => {
                        this.HttpRequest();
                    }}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For rendering condition based views you just have to return view on condition. To understand this let an example,

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           show = true
        }
     }

render(){
    if (this.state.show){
        return(
            <View>
                // this view visible when state.show is true
                <Text>Home is visible!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    } else if (!this.state.show){
        return(
            <View>
                // this view visible when state.show is false
                <Text>Home is not visible!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    } else {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Just visible, visible!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i will try do this and i come back to aswer if i did good. thank you for your time.

Comment: if (+1) { "Thanks!" } else { "Give it then." }